# Object creation with HashMap in java

Tags: java, performance, oop, nullpointerexception

I am trying to create object of a class as a value of HashMap in java. Below is my java code :

```
public interface Message {
    public String nextMessage(String data);
} 

public class DataMessage implements Message{
    private static String[] randomData;

    public DataMessage(String data) {
        randomData = data.split(",");
    }

    @Override
    public String nextMessage(String data) {
        int index = randomIndex.nextInt(randomData.length-1);
        return randomData[index];
    }
}
```

When I access that object it is returning null i.e. throwing null pointer exception.

I am trying to access that object as below :

```
public class MyMessage {

    public MyMessage() {
    }

    public static void main() {
        HashMap<String,Message> hash = new HashMap<String,Message>();
        if (some condition) {
            hash.put(key,new DataMessage("this is my data"));
        }

        <some code>

        hash.get(key).nextMessage();
        //Throws nullpointer exception
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help me to understand why this is happening?

I am beginner in java and trying to improve performance of this approach. Please suggest better approaches if any.

Comment: "key" is used twice, without being initialized.

Comment: assuming that you have instantiated your "key" maybe something is keeping you from entering your if condition. Check to make sure the ket really is in your hashmap

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't access to you `if(){}` so your `HashMap` is always empty for that you get `NullPointException` because when you try to use `hash.get(key).nextMessage();` the first part `hash.get(key)` is null so you can't make `null.nextMessage();`

so to solve your problem make sure that your HashMap is not empty and there are an element with this key.

```
if (hash .containsKey(key)) {
    //key exists
    hash.get(key).nextMessage();
} else {
    //key does not exists
    System.out.println("No key exist");
}
```

**Note**
I think you have some error in your function for example this method should return some thing or a `void`:

```
public RandomData(String data) {
     randomData = data.split(",");
}
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks for noticing the difference. Missed to replace the constructor name while replacing proprietary code with generic one. Updated now :)
And hashmap has many records. Just for understanding purpose, I have put sample code. I have debugged the code and verified that hashmap is not empty.

Comment: yes @user3150037 i know maybe your hashmap is not empty but you need to check if there are an element with this key in your hashmap or not if yes you can make `hash.get(key).nextMessage();` else you will get a NullPointException how you get it